# How to make fixed element no longer scroll with window at certain point?

Tags: javascript, css

Here's some background information, I've got a website with a shopping cart, and the checkout button along with the PayPal button and little images of various credit holders are on the right hand side of the screen and are set to "position: fixed;". They move with the window perfectly, except for when you get to the bottom of the page.

Previously my issue was the Checkout buttons going behind my footer, so I simply added a z-index of 1000 to remedy that as you can see below. [image: here]

Now obviously that still doesn't look right, and as you scroll back up, the Checkout follows and goes back to normal. The image above is not scrolled down all the way on the page. When scrolled all the way down, the bottom of the "Secure Payments by PayPal" box is below the "Exclusive Content, News, & Discounts" information.

What I would like to do is have the Checkout box still fixed to the window and scroll when the user scrolls, but when the bottom of the PayPal box is aligned with the bottom of that form window you see on the left, I would like for it to stop scrolling with the window, see my image below to see what I mean.
[image: align]

I am guessing that this is going to require JS, which is no issue at all. I'm not sure if fiddle is able to do that, I'm not too rehearsed with JavaScript.

Here is my code for the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
    #cart_details {
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: 76%;
    z-index: 1000;
    clear: none;
    position: fixed;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    #cart_details {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 63%;
    z-index: 1000;
    clear: none;
    position: fixed;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1320px){
    #cart_details {
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 760px;
    z-index: 1000;
    clear: none;
    position: fixed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with vanilla JavaScript to give you an idea to start with. You need to add an eventListener to detect the scroll, then compare the scroll position to the element to add and remove a class. In this example I'm changing the background color of a paragraph, but you can define the class as you need. It's pretty straightforward, using jQuery is even easier.

```js
var mine = document.getElementById('mine');
 var scrolltop = document.body.scrollTop;
 window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  scrolltop = document.body.scrollTop;
  if(scrolltop >= mine.offsetTop) {
   mine.classList.add("fixed");
  } else if(scrolltop < mine.offsetTop) {
   mine.classList.remove("fixed");
  }

 })
```

```css
p {
 font-size: 12px;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

::selection {
 color: red;
 background: yellow;
}


#mine {
 
}

.fixed {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet ham hock meatball pig meatloaf jowl, tail picanha pork drumstick venison tenderloin swine prosciutto rump. Turkey shank fatback porchetta chicken shankle flank short ribs corned beef ground round. Doner bacon fatback venison spare ribs, chuck bresaola hamburger corned beef landjaeger pork chop boudin prosciutto ground round capicola. Salami strip steak fatback corned beef pork belly bacon, kevin venison pork chop porchetta andouille picanha jerky. Burgdoggen pork chop capicola alcatra. Kevin ham jerky filet mignon prosciutto. Flank capicola leberkas, shoulder pork chop doner biltong prosciutto.</p>

<p>Cow ribeye t-bone beef. Shank t-bone chicken chuck. Shoulder boudin salami burgdoggen. Swine filet mignon meatball venison brisket burgdoggen shoulder frankfurter beef salami bresaola picanha pastrami jerky jowl. Tri-tip pork belly tail venison sirloin brisket turkey. Cupim turkey biltong, pancetta meatloaf venison kevin frankfurter burgdoggen boudin cow shankle shank andouille pork loin.</p>

<p>Porchetta kevin short ribs, shank cow pork chop burgdoggen rump bresaola. Andouille hamburger corned beef bresaola jerky pork rump. Pork chop ribeye filet mignon, flank chuck kielbasa cow rump leberkas frankfurter shankle pork loin jowl. Tri-tip spare ribs bresaola, short loin ham hock tenderloin short ribs boudin. Kevin ham doner, shank prosciutto chuck beef shankle pork bacon kielbasa. Pork bresaola brisket leberkas. Kevin ground round ball tip tongue salami prosciutto.</p>

<p id="mine">Salami sirloin kielbasa ham tail beef. Kielbasa pork chop tri-tip, jowl cow porchetta chuck turducken landjaeger frankfurter ball tip doner fatback. Bresaola andouille spare ribs jerky boudin doner chicken beef ribs meatloaf. Beef ribs pancetta jowl, burgdoggen shoulder tri-tip pastrami picanha venison chicken bresaola rump chuck. Ball tip alcatra capicola, burgdoggen flank short ribs doner tongue turkey pancetta frankfurter pork pork loin cow drumstick. Meatball drumstick picanha, meatloaf hamburger ham frankfurter ham hock jowl brisket ribeye chicken bacon. Bacon pork chop tongue meatloaf, chicken strip steak prosciutto burgdoggen landjaeger picanha tenderloin andouille pancetta sirloin.</p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>

<p>Biltong corned beef fatback tongue, tenderloin flank cow swine. Pork belly doner short loin beef shankle jerky. Shankle ball tip beef ribs burgdoggen picanha hamburger beef tongue filet mignon ground round ham hock. Bacon porchetta pork loin, short loin tri-tip shoulder tenderloin pancetta jowl jerky. Sausage jowl picanha, pork tri-tip corned beef pork belly meatball chicken cupim salami capicola ground round prosciutto swine. Landjaeger ball tip pork belly, spare ribs meatloaf beef ribs tenderloin ham picanha t-bone sirloin shoulder turkey porchetta short ribs.<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var winScrollTop;
var formBottom = $("#form").offset().top + $("#form").outerHeight();
var cart = $("#cart_details");

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var cartPosition = cart.offset();
    var cartBottom = cartPosition.top + cart.outerHeight();

    if (!winScrollTop && cartBottom >= formBottom) {
        winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        cart.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": formBottom - cart.outerHeight(),
            "left": cartPosition.left,
            "margin": 0
        });
    } else if (winScrollTop && $(window).scrollTop() <= winScrollTop) {
        winScrollTop = null;
        cart.removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aqa06974/

**Alternatively, you may conceder** [Sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) as another solution. It is a tiny and wonderful library that does lots of stuffs in the same regards.